# Python & Numpy - how to remove the last 2 digits of each number/element?

Tags: python, numpy

I have question:

I use numpy arrays and I got a bit stuck. So I have an array with years and months like this:

```
array([['202305'],
       ['202109'],
       ['202110'],
       ['202002'],
       ['202001'],
       ['202003']], dtype='<U6')
```

so, '202305' means: year 2023, in May. The thing is that I only need the year, so I would like to remove the last 2 digits so that I get an array like this:

```
array([['2023'],
       ['2021'],
       ['2021'],
       ['2020'],
       ['2020'],
       ['2020']], dtype='<U4')
```

I tried multiple things similar to this:

```
for jaar in hr_jaar:
    jaar = int(str(jaar)[0:4])
```

which gives the error that I got in the most cases but don't really know what it means:
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "['20"`

It should be quiet simple but I got stuck somehow :) really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in more detail at what the iteration is doing:

```
In [118]: for jaar in hr_jaar: 
     ...:     print(jaar, str(jaar)[0:4]) 
     ...:                                                                                
['202305'] ['20
['202109'] ['20
['202110'] ['20
['202002'] ['20
['202001'] ['20
['202003'] ['20
```

`hr_jaar` is (6,1) array, so `jaar` is (1,) array.  `str(...)` turns that array into a string, including the "['".

```
In [119]: for jaar in hr_jaar: 
     ...:     print(jaar[0], jaar[0][0:4]) 
     ...:                                                                                
202305 2023
202109 2021
202110 2021
202002 2020
202001 2020
202003 2020
```

`jaar[0]` takes that string out of the array, which can then be sliced.

But:

```
In [120]: for jaar in hr_jaar: 
     ...:     jaar = jaar[0][0:4]
```

does not change `hr_jaar`.  That's basic Python iteration behavior.

You have to collect the changed strings in a new list, as done with this list comprehension:

```
In [122]: [jaar[0][0:4] for jaar in hr_jaar]                                             
Out[122]: ['2023', '2021', '2021', '2020', '2020', '2020']
```

Using the `astype` is simpler, but I think you need to understand what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the elements to the other dtype:

```
hr_jaar.astype('<U4')
```

You get the error which you observe because your data is 2-dimensional and hence `jaar` is a 1-element array, e.g. `['202305']`. If you convert that to `str` that includes the brackets, i.e. `"['202305']"`.

Answer (score 0):

Another good way is to make a for loop go through the array and use the following in the loop. The loop would look like:

```
for i in range(The_Array.size()): 


    Original_String=The_Array[i]

    New_String=Original_String[:-2]
```